# SSH in Browser GCP Instance - Download Error

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an instance of Alfresco running in GCP. It all works fine and now I want to make some settings. For this I have to download and edit a file (alfresco-global.properties). I can connect to the instance using SSH-in-the-browser and use command "cd" to move to the appropriate directory. The corresponding file is located there:

```
/opt/alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties
```

If I now select "Download file" in the SSH browser and insert this path (including the file name), I get the message "Error". This also happens as root.

I am probably doing something fundamentally wrong there. Can someone give me instructions or recommend a link with info? (Except for GCP, I have already read them all).

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I can download other files from this directory. Only this (alfresco-global.properties) cannot. I thought maybe this file was locked by Tomcat and shut down Tomcat. But that did not bring success.

Comment: What the command `fuser -uv /opt/alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties` returns? Also, could you please provide the full text of the error message?

Comment: "-bash: fuser: command not found" Thanks a lot. Is there an alternate command?

Comment: First: "-bash: fuser: command not found" After getting "psmisc" I do not get any return to this command.

Comment: Alternatively, you might use `lsof /opt/alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties` to check if any process is working with the file. Both `fuser` and `lsof` should be available for installation from your Linux repository. In Debian `fuser` is part of the `psmisc` package, whereas `lsof` is a separate package. And what about the full text of the error message you receive trying to download the file?